# WSO2 MDM & Apple's Device Enrollment Program

Tags: wso2-iot

Has anyone successfully setup an in-house production WSO2 MDM server that is registered with Apple's DEP to automatically install MDM profile on iOS devices?  If yes are you able to manage and push VPP purchased APPs to the iOS devices?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the WSO2 EMM 2.0.0 does not support Apple's DEP based device monitoring. It is a feature that we're already working on and it will be available in the future releases.

Answer (score 0):

Both DEP support and VPP are some of the features we are working on currently. Will be available in future releases.